# What is use of synchronized method if we have synchronized block?

Tags: multithreading, block, synchronized

If I always call a method from a synchronised block then what is advantage of making any method as synchronized?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's just another way of writing the same thing. If your `synchronized` block exactly matches a method block, then it's just easier to read that way. Syntax sugar.

Which is easier?

```
public synchronized void myMethod() {
        // do stuff
}

public void myMethod() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```